# Declare variable in jndi.properties

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jndi

I want to know if it is possible to declare à custom int or integer in jndi.properties.

I'm doing a JMS program. And I want to "give" easly an int to the program.

I tried to find by myself, but I can't find anything interesting.

So can I or is jndi really formated to be use only by strict rules.

What I want to do in jndi.propreties:

```
#number of threads accepted
int.maxThreads = 3 

#queue.[jndiName] = [physicalName]
queue.MyQueue = MyQueue2
```

Then in java :

```
int maxThreadsTemp = (int) ctx.lookup("maxThreads");
```

I tryed but failed. I get the normal : "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: maxThreads"

So did I declared it wrong or is it just impossible to do so ?
Thanks in advance.

*Edit : I use ActiveMQ and for JNDI I used this url to do it : http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html

Comment: You'll need to say and tag your post with which jms provider and jndi provider you are using.

Comment: @Calanais I edited my question with the informations but I don't know the jndi provider actually I didn't know it had one. So I put the url I used to inspire my code.

Comment: Try to remove the int. prefix in your jndi properties. Also it may return a string value, so you can just convert that afterwards to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer : What I did was to forget the methode lookup(...)

```
ctx = new InitialContext(...);
int maxThreadsTemp = (int) ctx.lookup("maxThreads");
```

Instead I used a hashtable (much simpler):

```
ctx = new InitialContext(...);
Hashtable<?, ?> environment =  ctx.getEnvironment();
            String nbrThread = (String)  environment.get("maxThreads");
```

And in jndi.properties : `maxThreads = 5`      (thx to @Claus Ibsen)

Comment: Indeed I think that the best way to do that !